# asp.net mvc access to file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project, and part of my project is to print PDF files. Everything worked fine until this morning, when I added `System.Net.Mail` to send attached files. And, also worked fine after this, but when I tried to edit information, I got this error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'Content\StudentPdf\student54.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
```

I use `iTextSharp` to print PDFs, but it crashes at the next line of code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/StudentPdf/student" + id + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create))
```

How can I find out where my file is being used in my solution? My `PrintPdf` method is called before the `SendEmail` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are opening a file for reading, set its FileAccess and FileShare modes:

```
using(var readerFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
                                          FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
 // ...
}
```

In this case, this file won't be locked for reading or writing by other processes. Also don't forget the `using` part, which guaranties the release of resources.

Comment: I do how you said, but then it will be get me an error: Stream does not support writing. when I'm try to call doc.open method

Answer (score 0):

Are you you using TFS or other versioning tool?, maybe you included the file in your project and you have locked when you checkin, check this out.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_folders.asp) is a list of directios and its use in MVC:

**The App_Data folder is for storing application data.**

You can create a folder in `App_Data` as `ReportPdf` and not include you generate PDF files in the project to avoid blocking.

Comment: What do you mean about avoid blocking?

Comment: I have a rest for a hour, when returned to the project everything works fine. And after 5-7 updates problem appear again

Comment: Do you have a report generated inside the Project? Do you have it within the control of versioning?